# Logical expression evaluating to NA

Tags: r, logical-operators

In R, I have a function Outlier that accepts a numerical vector of length 3. I was trying this:

```
Outlier <- function(x) {
  x <- sort(x)
  if((x[1] < 1e-2) %% (x[1] > 1e-4))) {
print(x)
  }
...
```

However, I was getting the error message "Error in if (condition) { : argument is not interpretable as logical". After debugging, I found that the error was being produced whenever x[1] == 0. Somehow when x[1] == 0, the logical expression evaluates to NA. With other values it works as expected. Why is this, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Serious question: What do you think the %% operator does?

Comment: I see now that I typed %% when I meant to use &&

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent this you should revise your goal. The `NA` doesn't show up only when `x[1]` is zero, it shows up whenever `x[1] > 1e-4` evaluates to `FALSE`.

```
TRUE %% FALSE
[1] NA
FALSE %% FALSE
[1] NA
```

This obviously makes sense, I was only surprised to see it not return `NaN`:

```
1 %% 0
[1] NaN
0 %% 0
[1] NaN
```

Which leads me to conclude that the `R` parser is clever enough to recognize the difference between logical and numerical values.

Comment: Not related to the parser, logical values are coerced to integers here. Check out 1L %% 0L.

Comment: @Roland: Thanks, I should have checked it out before making a statement.